# How to document multiple variable declarations in PHPDoc

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

I'm using short syntax to define member variables of a class so instead of

```
private $a;
private $b;
private $c;
```

I use

```
private
    $a,
    $b,
    $c;
```

Now I use PHPDoc to tell the IDE of the type of each member like so:

```
/** @var classA */
private $a;
/** @var classB */
private $b;
/** @var classC */
private $c;
```

However this doesn't work with the short syntax:

```
private
    /** @var classA */
    $a,
    /** @var classB */
    $b,
    /** @var classC */
    $c;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd be surprised if PHPDoc supported documenting the short syntax declarations. Can't you just write them out longhand?

Comment: This is what I am doing at the moment however when there's many member vars it gets messy, I hoped there was some alternative syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not the answer you want to hear, but that you can't do. PHPDoc isn't as smart as you want it to be, though life on earth would be almost impossible without it.

Besides, things normally start to get messy when people stop following [PSR conventions](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/psr-huh--net-29314), like [declaring multiple properties per statement](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#42-properties). So, don't reinvent the wheel, if you don't like the generally accepted way – stick with it and you'll get over this soon enough ;)

Srsly…

Comment: I don't understand why declaring multiple properties per statement is considered bad practice though. It keeps the code cleaner, easier to read since you group vars etc. In languages like C++ you are forced to do it that way (private vars under a single "private:" label etc.).
Anyway, thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Haha this subject is more explosive than the dynamite. PSR is the god sent! It adds a great level of structure to a very forgiving  language. Many people don't like how others write their code, but many would make compromises to see others writing code in the same way as they do. This makes everyone's life easier at some point.

Comment: In addition of PSR-2, [PSR-12 (Extended Coding Style) also says you must not declare more than one property per statement](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#43-properties-and-constants).

Answer (score 5):

Actually, phpDocumentor 2.x does support the compound declaration, though using one docblock rather than many --
https://docs.phpdoc.org/3.0/guide/references/phpdoc/tags/var.html#var

Note that if you don't get the doc results you expect, it may be a bug (like the one shown here -- [phpDoc @var for compound statement isn't displayed correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067905/phpdoc-var-for-compound-statement-isnt-displayed-correctly)).

Comment: Please show the syntax how it is done according to the `phpdoc.org` link. Unfortunatly the link does not work anymore, so I can't find the correct syntax.

Comment: @RobinBastiaan link updated

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking at similar types; for example:

```php
/** @var string */
private $stringVariable;

/** @var string */
private $stringVariable2;

/** @var string */
private $anotherVariable;

/** @var string */
private $andMoreStringTypes;
```

you can ofcourse use `/** @var string */` for every rule - but you can also use **DocBlock templates**, like so:

```php
/**#@+
 * @var string
 */
private $stringVariable;
private $stringVariable2;
private $anotherVariable;
private $andMoreStringTypes;
/**#@-*/
```

Comment: I could not found any official documentation about this syntax, if you have one could you link it here that would be great :)

Comment: @AlexanderSchranz There's still a reference here: https://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.howto.pkg.html#basics.docblocktemplate - but it looks like this has been deprecated. Yet, it still works in most IDE's.